# How to calculate dynamically the percentage of non null values in each column of spark Data frame by importing files From S3?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I want to import files from S3 path dynamically using dates(for each date there is one file on S3 path)and after importing I want to calculate the percentage of non null values for each column of spark data frame for an entire year. In my case it is 2019.

Let say for the year 2019:

```
columns   non null percentage

Column1        80%
Column2        75%
Column3        57%
```

I tried coding it by myself but I am not sure if it will give me the appropriate output:

```
daterange = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01",end="2019-12-31")

for date in daterange

 df_clm= spark.read.parquet('s3:path/dt={date}')

    for col in df_clm.column
        null_cnt= df_clm[col].isna().sum()
        total= df_clm.count()
        percent= ((total-null_cnt)/total)*100
```

I think the above code will give me the output for each day(each file) i.e for 365 days(365 files) but I want to accumulate all the files and calculate the percentage for each column.

Note: All the files have same columns.

Can anyone please help me in coding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the non-null counts for each column from the Dataframe summary. The for-loop is really bad. Read your whole parquet file and filter the dates as you wish, and then do the below step.

```
df.show()

+---+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  aa|  bb|
|  2|null|  cc|
|  3|  dd|null|
|  4|  ee|null|
|  5|  ff|null|
+---+----+----+

summary = df.describe().filter("summary = 'count'")
columns = df.columns
counts  = df.count()

summary.rdd \
  .flatMap(lambda row: map(lambda i: (columns[i-1], row[i]), range(1, len(row)))) \
  .toDF(['col', 'count']) \
  .withColumn('ratio', col('count') / counts * 100) \
  .show(10, False)

+----+-----+-----+
|col |count|ratio|
+----+-----+-----+
|id  |5    |100.0|
|val1|4    |80.0 |
|val2|2    |40.0 |
+----+-----+-----+
```